# Что из себя представляет networkd, networkmanager, wpa_supplicant и тд

Tags: linux, сеть, archlinux

Ставлю себе arch linux и возникла проблема - не могу разобраться в настройке сети (wifi). В туториалах этому не посвещают внимания, т.к. все ставят арч на виртуалку, а там уж сеть сама определяется, как я понял с помощью dhcpcd. Так вот вопрос в следующем: что из себя представляют и чем отличаются - networkd, networkmanager, wpa_supplicant, iwd, netctl.
Не ругайте за возможно глупый вопрос, я новичок в этом деле:)

Comment: Есть же прекрасная вики: [в целом настройка сети](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration), [конкретно wireless (тут есть сравнения)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless), [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd), [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager), [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant), [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd), [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Netctl).

Comment: Все статьи читал кроме той, которая с сравнениями. Спасибо большое

Comment: `systemd-networkd` просто работает, всё остальное требует каких-то танцев с бубном, если нужно что-либо *чуть больше простейшёй конфигурации*.

Comment: @0andriy а как вы настраиваете Wi-Fi в `systemd-networkd` без дополнительных пакетов? —https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-networkd#Wireless_adapter.